# How to get First Value of JSON with Multiple Values for 1 Key (With JSON Parser for Google Sheets, on Yahoo Finance API)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance, jsonparser

I included the JSON Parser Module for my Google Sheets and it works very fine to Parse Json Modules from Yahoo Finance.

I Struggle a Bit with the Financial, and Balance Sheets where 1 Key has more Values (for each Quarter or Year) and How to address them with the module

Here The JSON to Yahoo Finance
http://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/GLJ.DE?modules=balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly

Here how the Page looks like normal
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GLJ.DE/financials?p=GLJ.DE

I used  https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON this module to Scrape JSON from Web

Now when I Use this Formula in my GoogleSheet it works well, but gives me every Value for the "netTangibleAsset" Key. I only want to have the 1 one (the most recent one) Displayed instead of all in the row

```
=ImportJSON(AQ2,"/quoteSummary/result/balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly/balanceSheetStatements/netTangibleAssets/raw","noInherit, noTruncate,noHeaders")
```

(while AQ2 is my Prebuilt String to the JSON as mentioned above)

[image: Picture of my Sheet how it Imports 4 Values instead of 1]

Would be Thankful if someone knows how to Import only 1 Value instead of all which belong to the Key

Comment: Welcome to [so]. How do you know which value is the most recent? Show what you tried to get the value that you require and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi Ruben. when u open the Above mentioned JSON  Query2 of Yahoo Finance. The Raw Value behind the frist mentioned
 "netTangibleAssets":{"raw":1131628000,"fmt":"1.13B","longFmt":"1,131,628,000"}

is always the most recent value which i want to grab. but if i pull it with the formula in the question i get all 4 "netTangibleAsset" raw Values which are in this JSON